# Detect operating system from Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, user-agent

I am developing a Chrome extension, and I need to detect which operating system Chrome is running on but i can't seem to find any info on how to do it. Please Help. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 23):

Recently added, you can use the [getPlatformInfo method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getPlatformInfo) in Chrome's own API:

```
chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo(function(info) {
    // Display host OS in the console
    console.log(info.os);
});
```

Comment: Note that it won't work in [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Answer (score 6):

You would need to search for OS name and version inside `window.navigator.appVersion`.

If you just want to know a platform, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155032/operating-system-detection-by-java-or-javascript/4155078#4155078). You can enhance the code by searching for other [user agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference).

Here is [a detailed list of Chrome user agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) (click on links to see what they mean).

Comment: I'd rather use `navigator.platform`

Answer (score 0):

I guess `navigator.platform` would be more suitable but for me the following script that I often use based on `navigator.platform` suffices:

```
const ua = navigator.userAgent

const getBrowser = (): 'Opera' | 'Chrome' | 'Firefox' | 'Safari' | 'IE' | 'Edge' | 'Unknown' | undefined => {
  if (ua.indexOf('Opera') > -1) {
    return 'Opera'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1) {
    return 'Chrome'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Firefox') > -1) {
    return 'Firefox'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Safari') > -1) {
    return 'Safari'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('MSIE') > -1) {
    return 'IE'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Trident') > -1) {
    return 'IE'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Edge' || 'Chrome') > -1) {
    return 'Edge'
  }
  return 'Unknown'
}

const getOS = (): 'Windows' | 'Mac' | 'Linux' | 'Android' | 'iOS' | 'Unknown' => {
  if (ua.indexOf('Windows') > -1) {
    return 'Windows'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Mac') > -1) {
    return 'Mac'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Linux') > -1) {
    return 'Linux'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('Android') > -1) {
    return 'Android'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('iPhone') > -1) {
    return 'iOS'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('iPad') > -1) {
    return 'iOS'
  }
  if (ua.indexOf('iPod') > -1) {
    return 'iOS'
  }
  return 'Unknown'
}

export { getBrowser, getOS }
```