# Limit Google Chrome extension to select platforms

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have an extension which talks to a native application. This application only works on macOS or Windows. But when I add the extension to my browser, it is also synchronized automatically to platforms where it does not make sense such as Linux or Chrome OS.

I'd figured there would be an option in the [`manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) to limit the app to specific platforms but I can't find anything like that. Am I correct? Or is there a solution?

Answer (score -2):

**Extensions will be installed based on chrome login.** So it will be installed on all devices with chrome login.

You can programmatically **enable/disable your scripts after checking for supported platform OS**.

Use this API in background script to collect platform details - [API Link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPlatformInfo).

Related question: [Detect operating system from Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376979/detect-operating-system-from-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Yes, I know about how I can not run my scripts after checking for the supported platform.
But my question is: how to only limit the extension to specific platforms, so that it does not get installed on Chrome OS in the first place?