# Detect the underlying OS in a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-app

Since packaged apps can run on different platforms, is there any way to distinguish between Windows and Mac ?

I would like to show some help vis-à-vis keyboard shortcuts and being able to detect the OS would help in for example showing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> accordingly.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155032/operating-system-detection-by-java-or-javascript/4155078#4155078

Comment: Nice, just learned about `<kbd>`

Comment: Do apps have the same APIs available as 'extensions'?  If so: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getPlatformInfo

Comment: @hometoast thanks, it is mentioned here http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-getPlatformInfo but it seems to be available in Chrome Canary (v30) for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.navigator` in JS. Typically that will have the information you're looking for. Probably in window.navigator.platform.

Comment: looks like using a combination of `navigator.platform` and `navigator.appVersion` does the job, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the new `chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo` API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-getPlatformInfo, available since *Chrome 29*).