# Any chrome API to get platform info?

Tags: google-chrome-app

As you might already know, chrome app on windows & mac & linux will be deprecated.

So, I need to show an alert on my app. but it should not be shown on chromeos.

But it seems there's not such API to determine platform.

Comment: [chrome.runtime.getPlatformInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPlatformInfo)?

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you that's exactly that I want!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect the underlying OS in a Chrome Packaged App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153367/detect-the-underlying-os-in-a-chrome-packaged-app)